# ¿Cómo podría impedir que se escriba un punto y/o simbolos especiales en un input de tipo number en html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo un input de tipo number:

```
<input type='number' class='form-control' id='input_meses'>
```

Cuyo valor a recibir debe ser obligatoriamente un número entero, sin simbolos o carácteres especiales. Pero éste me permite escribir todo lo mencionado; ¿hay alguna manera mediante javascript, html, jquery o alguna librería que solo le permite digitar números al usuario?

Comment: Es un simple input number ... `<input type="number" id="input_meses" class="form-control" name="numeros" min="10" max="100">`. Mira [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) para obtener info sobre esto..

Comment: La respuesta de @Jaime Menéndez es completamente válida, sobre todo la que usa REGEX, pero tiene el problema en navegadores basados en Chromium que si presionas caracteres no válidos el caret se regresa al inicio de input. Considera esta respuesta en SO como alternativa https://stackoverflow.com/a/32784911/7023800c

Answer (score 4):

Usa algo como:

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = Math.round(this.value);"/>
```

De esta manera el usuario no va a poder digitar otra cosa que no sea números enteros. Ante cualquier intento el número será redondeado.

Alternativamente usando `regex`:

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');"/>
```

Comment: +1 por el regex. En un navegador que no soporte campos de tipo number (no sé cuales podrán ser, pero está especificado en la documentación así que mejor hacerle caso?) estos se cambian automaticamente por un type="text", dejando el `Math.round(this.value);` roto cuando el usuario introduce una letra.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
function validarNumeros(event) {
let keycode = event.keyCode
let string = ".!@#$%^/[]{}`&*()_=+<>:;´¨"
string = string + `"`
//Entre 48 y 57- entre 96 y 105--8, 190, 110,16
if ((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || (keycode >= 96 && keycode <= 105) || keycode == 8 || keycode == 9 || keycode == 190 || keycode == 110 || keycode == 16) {
    if (!string.includes(event.key))
        return true
}
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Te explico como funciona, uso los eventos para identificar que teclas estan pulsandose obteniendo su keycode, tuve al princio un problema porque los numeros arriba del teclado tienen el mismo keycode cuando hay combinaciones de teclas (por ejemplo el numero 6, con la combinacion shift+6), por eso use ese string de caracteres especiales y lo valide con .includes
y asi quedaria tu input

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='validarNumeros(this)' />
```